# How do I read JQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery for some time now, but there is one thing that still riddles me.

Look at this function:

```
jQuery.each(function(index) { ... });
jQuery.each(function(index, value) { ... });
```

How do I know - without looking at examples (or api.jquery.com) - that the callback function has an
`index` (or `index, value`) as parameters?

Another one:

```
jQuery.ajax({url: "test.jsp", cache: false}).done(function( data ) { ... });
```

How do I know, that jQuery.ajax can have a JSON object `url` and `cache` and whatever? 
And more, where is that `done` coming from?

AFAIK, there is little support from the IDEs in terms of code completion, so this seems a complicated issue for JS parsers of IDEs.

Thank you.

Regards,
Bernie

PS: Naturally I'm a Java man, JS is still weird to me ;-)

Comment: You can read the docs: api.jquery.com

Comment: Got to read the API and see what the function offers.

Comment: Depending on your editor, some of them have support for code quasi-support completion as well.   Due to the extremely flexible nature of JavaScript and the fact that one can add or remove methods at will -- all the way through the prototype stack -- makes real honest code completion near impossible.

Comment: You read the docs. As for IDE support, Visual Studio does a little better than it used to with this, but it's complicated by the dynamic nature of Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to take a look at the [source code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.each) of [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

It shows that the callback function is [`called`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) with two arguments.

```
callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]);
```

Where `i` refers to the array index, `obj[i]` refers to the array at subscript `i`. Since the callback is called with the `this` value referring to the array at subscript i, you can also access the array at the current iteration via `this`

Answer (score 2):

Your read the jQuery documentation, which lists all possible arguments a method can take.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) site answers all of these questions. (Bookmark it!)

For example, the page on [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) tells you that the callback function has the signature `function(index, Element)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

- check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) if you have an internet connection
- if no connection available, use `console.log();` to print the source-code of the function like this:

`console.log($.each);`

- as pointed by Jeremy, you could also add `console.log(arguments);` in your callback function. It will print the passed arguments and you could deduce what they mean.
- another option would be using an *IDE* like *Webstorm* that has incredibly good integration.

Comment: Another option:  I often use `console.log(arguments)` inside the call back function to see what is given to me.